# After newest W10 1709 update computer freezes during heavy internet usage

Tags: windows-10, internet, freeze, windows-10-v1709

I checked everything and even if there is only one program used (internet browser, battle.net app or anything else) computer starts freezing. In task manager System process uses a lot of CPU(30-50%). This is first time I've ever saw something like this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found solution. You need to update your SSD firmware drivers (Mine SSD is OCZ Agility 3). I upgraded firmware from 2.22 to 2.25 and now everything works fine. Here is link to firmware update software for OCZ SSD drives:
https://www.ocz.com/us/download/ssd-utility#hide

EDIT: Above information is false problem started reappearing. Current fix that works is removing fast boot option in Windows Power Settings. Link:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Go ahead and look up the drivers for all of your components, there may be better performance from updating them also.  Graphics cards especially.